# Como acessar dados do SQLite do Android em tempo real (DEBUG)

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea

Como posso acessar os dados contidos no banco local do aparelho Android, garantindo que a informação esteja atualizada?

Minha IDE é IntelliJ IDEA e utilizo o recurso de conexão com o Banco de Dados da mesma para Debugar, mas algumas vezes a ferramenta perde a comunicação com o DB e continua retornando querys com valores desatualizados (acho que a IDE salve o Banco localmente e faça as consultas dessa cópia).

Copiar a database para uma máquina local não me atende pois preciso debugar as alterações que meu app faz no DB do smartphone.

Poderiam me informar outras opções para realizar o Debug?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Answer (score 1):

Fala Felipe,

Essa foi uma dúvida que eu sempre tive, postei em milhares de lugares e fóruns e nada!

O que eu consegui foi um método, que exporta o arquivo **.bd** do SQLite, e com esse arquivo consigo visualizá-lo em um programa como o [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) por exemplo.

É um jeito bem lusitano, mas pelo menos pra mim funciona, faça o seguinte:

Coloque esse método na sua MainActivity, ou qualquer que seja a classe principal da sua aplicação:

```
private void banco() {

    File f = new File("/data/data/br.com.packagedoseuprojeto/databases/ame.db");
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    FileOutputStream fos=null;

    try
    {
        fis=new FileInputStream(f);
        fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/db_dump.db");
        while(true)
        {
            int i=fis.read();
            if(i!=-1)
            {fos.write(i);}
            else
            {break;}
        }
        fos.flush();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {}
    }

}
```

Agora chame o método **banco()** dentro do OnCreate da sua classe.

Como você pode reparar na seguinte linha:

```
File("/data/data/br.com.packagedoseuprojeto/databases/banco.db");
```

Você deve alterar o package, para o endereço da sua aplicação. Esse é o caminho onde ficará o arquivo **banco.db** no seu device, depois você consegue abrir o arquivo no programa [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

É um jeito bem complexo de seguir, mas tem funcionado pra mim, se você conseguir algo mais fácil vou ficar feliz em saber também.

Se tiver alguma dúvida pode me mandar msg privada.

Abraços.

Comment: Hum, não me atende diretamente, mas me deu a idéia de escrever Logs com as infos que eu preciso. Talvez testes do JUnit possam me atender também. Se funcionar eu posto aqui novamente. Grato.